# Simple application in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html

I have tried to run AngularJS application, I have two views:

1. view1.html
2. view2.html
3. index.html in which it's linked to view1 and view2

But when I click on this it does not go to the html, and it does not display anything, I have code as follows:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body>
<h3>hiiiiiiiii</h3>
<a href="#/view1">view1</a>
<a href="#/view2">view2</a>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="js/app/app.js"/>
<script src="js/app/controllers.js" />
<script src="lib/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/Angular/angular-route.min.js"/>
<script src="lib/Angular/angular.js"/>


</body>
</html>
```

partials/view1.html

```
 <div ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
 <p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>
</div>
```

partials/view2.html

```
<div ng-controller="View2Ctrl">
 <p>This is the partial for view 2.</p>
 </div>
```

controllers.js

```
  var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
  alert("hiiii");
   app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  alert("hiiii");

   }]);
   app.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  alert("hiiii");

 }]);
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

   // Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
 angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
   'myApp.controllers'
  ]).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html',
        controller: 'View2Ctrl'});
   $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  }]);
```

Comment: What are your errors? How's about a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You just need load `angular.js` or `angular.min.js` not both of them.

The order of loaded java scripts is important, and if you try to use library which is not loaded first you will get error.

You should reorder java script link:

```
<script src="lib/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/Angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/controllers.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

typo here: 
`<html ng-app="myapp">` vs `angular.module('myApp', []);`
app name must be exactly the same (this is a common typo which happens to all of us)

Comment: I done all things above but it is not entered into contrlollers....its not display alert message for any link